# Laravel root path post method

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a form so when I click submit it goes to root url with post method. I created following

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('send'), 'method' => 'post')) }}
...
{{ Form::close() }}
```

and in routes

```
Route::get('/', 'Controller@home');
Route::post('/', 'Controller@home')->name('send');
```

But the $request value from controller is null and the method is get instead of post.

Comment: you have same route url with same method?

Comment: Do I have to create another method?

Comment: if you have get and post method with same url but functionality is different than you should

Comment: Yes, its basic. First read documentation.

Comment: Do you really want `get` and `post` goes to  `Controller@home` ?

Comment: @Sohel0415 Can you eloborate on why he should have different methods?

Comment: as I said in my previous comment, If functionality is different then he should

Comment: Can you maybe edit your question and post the code for your `home()` method?

Comment: @Sohel0415 Why is that? I see nothing wrong with having GET and POST  point to the same method

Comment: I didn't say anything about any problem in this regard, i just ask a question and he ask another without answering and i just answered that question, may be you could read all comments from the start, that may helps

Comment: @Sohel0415 Nevermind

Comment: @kerbholz Please don't misunderstand me, i like question, sometimes it helps us to understand better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two route with identical beginnings ("\") pointing to the same controller function.

Try replacing the second one with something like

```
Route::post('/home', 'Controller@homepost')->name('send');
```

Just duplicate your home method and make sure you have something like:

```
public function homepost (Request $request)
{ .... }
```

Comment: The beginnings are "/", not "\". And it is totally valid to have GET and POST routes point to the same controller method.

Comment: both routes are not same, one is for `get`  another is for `post`, so both are different. No need to change from `/` to `/home` or any.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `method=>post` with `route`, it is used with `url` [read in docs](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#opening-a-form). Change your `Form::open` like as below

Either

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'send']) }}
```

Or

```
{{ Form::open( ['url' => '/','method' => 'post'] ) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Route::any()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#basic-routing) If you want same url or function to response with multiple type requests like get, post etc.

```
Route::any('/', 'Controller@home');
```

Or you could use `Route::match()`.

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', Controller@home');
```